# Register 32 bit COM DLL to 64 bit Windows 7

Tags: dll, windows-7, com

I have a 32 bit COM component DLL and this DLL is written in Delphi.
It's a Win32 DLL.
I want to use this DLL in my Visual C# project on .NET platform.

I can't add reference to this DLL in the project.
I try to register it in Command Prompt as Administrator in Windows 7 64 bit, but I get this error:

> Check if the module is compatible with an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe.

First I put DLL file to windows/system32 folder. Then I open Command Prompt as Administrator. I write `regsvr32 huginalpha.dll` and execute this command. But I get the error. what can I do?

Comment: see this post about the 0x8007000B Error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007967/net-framework-error-hresult-0x8007000b/36353971#36353971

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The problem is likely you try to register a 32-bit library with 64-bit version of regsvr32. [See this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282747) - you need to run regsvr32 from windows\SysWOW64 for 32-bit libraries.

Comment: +1, indeed.  And that DLL should *not* be stored in c:\windows\system32 either, that's for 64-bit components.

Comment: Right, so the file called 32 is actually 64 bit, and the 32-bit version is in a directory called WOW64.

Comment: Sounds like more recent versions of regsvr32 may deal with this better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935163/registering-a-32-bit-dll-with-64-bit-regsvr32

Comment: That's curious. It's unclear how a 64-bit version of regsvr32 would identify that the .dll is 32-bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Was struggling so much with a way to register correct a 64 bit .dll file and was using the wrong command `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe .\my.dll` instead of using `C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe .\my.dll`.

Answer (score 30):

For 32 bit DLLS in Windows 64 bit platforms:

1. Copy whatever.dll to `c:\windows\sysWOW64\`
2. Open a CMD prompt AS ADMINISTRATOR (very important)

In the CMD window:

1. `CD c:\windows\sysWOW64\`
2. `regsvr32 whatever.dll`

You will then be executing the 32-bit regsvr (`c:\windows\sysWOW64\regsvr.exe`) on a 32 bit dll

Comment: +1 Your stressing on the point of running as administrator saved my life! :)

Comment: If you don't run as administrator it will say that the installation was successful, but it won't be registered. No other feedback you will receive (dam you, Microsoft!).

Answer (score 4):

I believe, things have changed now. On My **Win 2008 R2** Box, I was able to register a 32 bit dll with a 64 bit regsvr32 as the 64 bit version can detect the target bitness and spawn a new 32 bit regsvr32 from %SYSWOW% folder.

Refer: [Registering a 32 bit DLL with 64 bit regsvr32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18935732/977038)

Comment: `regsvr32` has been working around bitness issues for long time, I suppose from the very start. If you a reg'ging a 32-bit DLL with 64-bit `regsvr32`, the latter detects the problem and starts internally 32-bit version of `regsvr32` and forwards registration there. This works well in the opposite direction as well.

Comment: @RomanR.: I would have guessed but seeing this SO question and the KB article support.microsoft.com/kb/282747, this would make me wonder.

Answer (score 2):

http://onerkaya.blogspot.com/2013/03/register-com-dll-on-windows-64-bit.html

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {...} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

if you try this;

c:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe < filename >.dll

you can still take this exception. so IIS- pool Advanced settings, Enable 32 bit application : true ;)

Comment: IIS-> pool Advanced settings, Enable 32 bit application : true this really solved the problem. +1 for it.

Answer (score 2):

To register a comm .dll or .ocx on Windows 7 32-bit, do the following:

Copy .dll or .ocx to `c:\windows\system32`
Type cmd in Run menu, it will search cmd.exe, right click and click `Run as Administrator`

It will show a prompt at `c:\windows\system32`

Type

`regsvr32 ocxname.ocx` to register .ocx

or

type `regsvr32 dllname.dll` to register .dll

Comment: for xp also tested

Answer (score 0):

put the dll in system32 or syswow32 directory, and use appropriate regsvr32 to register it.
wiered that even though it gave failed to register error, I rebooted my WIN 7 64 AND my vb app loaded the dll just fine!!

Answer (score 0):

If problem not resolved, when using SysWoW64 version of regsvr32, make sure all library dependencies have same archetecture. For example, when

`regsvr32 lib_x86.dll` fails to register library, and
  `%SystemRoot%\SysWow64\regsvr32 lib_x86` also fails, try to load `lib_x86` to Dependency Walker application to see whole list of dependencies. If any item have 64-bit archetecture, here is the reason, why `regsvr32` fails to load 32-bit library.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it at Framework64.

Example:

- 32 bit

  ```
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe D:\DemoIconOverlaySln\Demo\bin\Debug\HandleOverlayWarning\AsmOverlayIconWarning.dll /codebase
  ```
- 64 bit

  ```
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe D:\DemoIconOverlaySln\Demo\bin\Debug\HandleOverlayWarning\AsmOverlayIconWarning.dll /codebase
  ```

Comment: This (regasm.exe) is for .NET assemblies only.

Comment: Ok. I answered the question on, important that you understand the level. NET assemblies how

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error "The module may compatible with this version of windows" for both version of RegSvr32 (32 bit and 64 bit). I was trying to register a DLL that was built for XP (32 bit) in Server 2008 R2 (x64) and none of the Regsr32 resolutions worked for me. However, registering the assembly in the appropriate .Net worked perfect for me.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe

Answer (score 0):

Below link saved the day

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229076(VS.80).aspx

use the relevant RegSvcs as specified in the above link

c:\Windows\Microsoft. NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegSvcs.exe ....\Shared\Your.dll /tlb:Your.tlb