# COM exception 0x80040154 when hosting WCF service in Windows Service or IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7, windows-services

I have a WCF service (C#), which I can build and run in Visual Studio 2010 (through Cassini Development Server).  I connect a console client app to that service and all works great.  The service itself loads a single COM object and all my code is working as expected (so far).

However, if I host this service in a Windows Service and install the service with sc or installutil (locally or remotely), and then connect the console client app to that same service, it still connects and disconnects ok, but when I call a service method that loads the COM object, I get an exception.  I have witnessed this exception whenever I host the service in a Windows Service or in IIS7 64-bit.

Obviously the COM object has been regsvr32'd on my machine and the service can load the COM object when hosted through the debugger.  I've even stepped right over the COM loading bit, the object looks great and I use it.  We also have other applications that use this same COM object.

I think this has (maybe) something to do with the fact that it is a (x86) .dll, and my development environment is 64-bit, and for some reason the Cassini Development Server can load the COM object, but when I host the service as a Windows Service or in IIS, either the $path$ variable or some environment issue is not allowing it to find/load the COM object.

As for when hosting in IIS, I did make a new pool and Enable 32-bit applications, but I still had trouble loading the COM object.  As for a Windows Service I'm not sure what I can do...

Pardon me if my Google searching was not effective, but I've been having trouble finding this exact situation.

Here is the standard not-registered COM exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException\`1 was unhandled
Message=Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {BB9F026E-EC18-449F-84AA-677225967C07} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at methodname(String product, String options, Int32 quantity)
   at methodname(String product, String options, Int32 quantity) in ...\Reference.cs:line 70
   at ....Program.Main(String[] args) in ...\Program.cs:line 72
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

Comment: Sorry for posting too much and scaring everyone away.  I just like to be as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem was that I wasn't registering the .dll with the special 64-bit program (still called regsvr32), inside the SysWOW64 directory of Windows.

See:
[Register 32 bit COM DLL to 64 bit Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439845/register-32-bit-com-dll-to-64-bit-windows-7/3440419#3440419)

Actually I found this solution before I posted, and thought I'd tried it and was still getting the exception, but perhaps I was wrong.  This solution seems to have worked.  It might even have required a server restart or at least IIS restart.