# regsvr32 error: the module was loaded but the entry point was not found

Tags: windows, dll, vb6, ocx, regsvr32

People here use an old compiled VB program, the last version is 16 years old. It works on some machines but not on others, all with the same 1709 version and updates of Windows 10.

Where it does not work a message says either that `msdatlst.ocx` or `msdatgrd.ocx` is not registered. Then when I try to register with `regsvr32 'MSDATGRD.OCX'` there is a message `"the module was loaded but the entry-point was not found"`. The same command is successful in the machines where the program works.

I did read some questions here but none of the answers solved it for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Run cmd.exe as an administrator and try regsvr32 "path_to_msdatgrd.ocx".

Comment: Also, try registering any other ocx or COM/ActiveX dll file.
If the problem still persists try Process Monitor to troubleshoot it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59463345/distributing-visio-addin-developed-in-vb6/59466130#59466130

If nothing helps, try with a small setup application for your ocx files. You could make it using Visual Studio or some setup tools like Setup Factory.

Comment: VB6 is 32 bit so you must use the 32 bit regsrv32 in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` and as mentioned Run As Admin.

Comment: @Smith: Yes I did it as admin

Comment: @Mark: Ah! Now I see that there are two versions of `regsvr32`. In my machine both are successfully executed. I will check in a machine where the program does not work.

Comment: @Mark I thought the same at first, but then I read this other Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935163/registering-a-32-bit-dll-with-64-bit-regsvr32  Now I'm not sure.

Comment: Try creating a proper deployment package instead of manually copying stuff around and tweaking it.

Comment: It sounds like the ocx might be corrupt.  I agree with Bob77 about using an install set to resolve this issue.  But another option would be to copy a working ocx and trying to register it.

Comment: @Brian:  The two `ocx` come from the same server in all machines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Mark's comment and all the others. The problem was indeed what version of `regsvr32` was executed.

In the machines where it was possible to register the `ocx` the default version is at `\windows\syswow64` and in those where that was not possible at `\windows\system32`. Then I did run the `syswow64` one and the registration succeeded and the program now works.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the .def file is specified, otherwise, the required `DllRegisterServer` function will not be exported.