# IIS and IISExpress with COM libraries

Tags: c#, iis, com

My Web Application working with COM library, I use this code:

```cs
Type headType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Eapi.Head");
dynamic head = null;
head = Activator.CreateInstance(headType);
```

And I have some problem with understanding working IIS. When I debug my webapp in VisualStudio, running IISExpress and all work. But after publication project on IIS, application is not find COM library.

> HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)

IIS on same computer as I'm develop project.

Im registry this dll 2 ways:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>regsvr32.exe c:\EOS\Delo\API\Eapi.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd ..
C:\Windows>cd SysWOW64
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>regsvr32.exe c:\EOS\Delo\API\Eapi.dll
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>
```

Comment: Should be 32/64 bitness problem, registering twice as described does not make sense to me - you will still register one of the bitnesses. You should be able to switch bitness in IIS pool settings (toggle "Enable 32-bit applications" advanced setting).

Comment: @RomanR.Oh my god! Yes! its work. My bad. I solve this problem the third day and have no idea "whats wrong". Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to `0x80040154` `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` and you are sure you registered COM server, the likely problem is 32/64 bitness mismatch.

Regardless of which regsvr32 you use, [it would register in-process COM server with the bitness of the DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18941626/868014).

IIS application pool has its own bitness setting and when the two mismatch your in-process COM server becomes unavailable.

Typical solutions are either build DLL for the other bitness and register respectively, or change IIS application pool bitness to reach the matching, [see instructions here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/IIS-7-and-IIS-8-Enable-32-bit-Applications-in-Application-Pool-of-IIS-Server.aspx):

[image]