# How do I load a 32 bit dll into a surrogate process for use in a 64 bit application

Tags: c++, dll, com, dllregistration

I'm trying to start a surrogate process for a legacy dll that I need use, I know I need to run this dll in a surrogate process since it's 32 bit and I can't run this in 64 bit space.

However I'm very confused about how to do this.

```
CLSID CLSID_x86DLL;
LPCOLESTR converted_cslid = L"{BEB800E3-F4D2-11D1-8B1A-0060B0A32AFE}";
CLSIDFromString(converted_cslid, &CLSID_x86DLL);
HRESULT hResult;

HRESULT hr = CoGetClassObject(CLSID_x86DLL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, NULL, IID_IClassFactory, (void**)&hResult);
```

I thought this should start the surrogate process however it returns "class not registered", but

`HINSTANCE hIns = ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "regsvr32", bdcComDLL, NULL, NULL);`

*should* register it? I've also manually went into the registry and added values where  I thought they were supposed to be.

How can I get this running in the system-suppilied surrogate? (dllhost.exe)

Comment: How are you registering the DLL [*as a surrogate*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/dll-surrogates)? Is there logic in the DLL’s `DllRegisterServer` for that? `regsvr32` by itself does not register surrogates. Also, if you are calling `regsvr32` from a 64bit process, make sure you are calling the 32bit version of `regsvr32` and not the 64bit version.

Comment: I went into the registry manually and added the surrogate entries by adding a string "DllSurrogate" under the AppID entry for the dll, and I am calling regsvr32 from a 64 bit process, but I'm under the impression it registers the target dll as whatever bitness it is.

Comment: ‘*I am calling regsvr32 from a 64 bit process, but I'm under the impression it registers the target dll as whatever bitness it is*” - that is incorrect. There are separate 32bit and 64bit versions of regsvr32. The 32bit can register only 32bit DLLs. The 64bit version can register only 64bit DLLs. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/249873/how-to-use-the-regsvr32-tool-and-troubleshoot-regsvr32-error-messages

Comment: Yes that's true, there are different regsvr32's, but according to [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935163/registering-a-32-bit-dll-with-64-bit-regsvr32) regsvr32 will use the appropriate version to whatever the dll is supposed to be, and it DOES tell me it is successful. @RemyLebeau

Comment: that may be true now for modern Windows, but that wasn’t always the case in older versions