# Merging PDF with pdfforge.dll in VBA on Windows x64

Tags: windows, excel, pdf-generation, excel-2007, vba

So I'm working around a macro that should merge some pdf. The code is pretty simple and work well using a dll given by PDFCreator setup (pdfforge.dll), but only on Windows 32Bits (XP or 7).

Here is the code

```
Dim Pdf As Object
Set Pdf = CreateObject("pdfforge.pdf.pdf")

Pdf.MergePDFFiles_2 FR1, Target & "FusionFR1.pdf", True
Pdf.MergePDFFiles_2 FR2, Target & "FusionFR2.pdf", True
Pdf.MergePDFFiles_2 FR3, Target & "FusionFR3.pdf", True
Pdf.MergePDFFiles_2 FR4, Target & "FusionFR4.pdf", True
```

Note that FR1, FR2, FR3 and FR4 are just some array of string which contains the path of those pdf I'm trying to merge.

So as I said, this code work well on any computer with Windows 32 Bits, as long as the version of PDFCreator provide the pdfforge.dll. But on a Windows 64 Bits, I've got an "Excel Automation Error" on
**Set Pdf = CreateObject("pdfforge.pdf.pdf")**

I guess this is a dll which work only on a 32 bits system and by default, a windows 64 bits try to work through a 64 bits environment. So I tried to register this dll for the 32 bits environment through two methods without having satisfying result :

- [Register 32 bit COM DLL to 64 bit Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439845/register-32-bit-com-dll-to-64-bit-windows-7)
- http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/

Hope you guys could help me :)

PS: I'm working on Excel 2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to make it work !

I mainly use the Assembly Registration Tool, regasm.exe

First, I've made sure that the dll was not registered anywhere, that is to say both in Framework 32 Bits and 64 Bits, using regasm.exe with the /u argument.

Then I registered the dll in framework\v2.0.50727 **using the /codebase argument** (I've read from multiple source this argument is the key)

Finally, I've created a text file named *excel.exe.config* in the root of the excel directory which contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

This should force excel to use framework v2.

Hope this could help someone one day ;)