# LotusScript agent for WIA causes error when run on Domino server

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, wia

I have a LotusScript agent that runs after new mail arrives.  The agent returns:

> err 208 Cannot create automation object

when enabled on the server, but runs fine when changed to run from the menu on selected docs using the Notes client.

```
Dim oImage As Variant
Dim oProcess As Variant
Dim lngH As Long, lngW As Long

'Build the object   -- works from Notes client but not from server agent...
Set oImage = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")

'load it    
oImage.LoadFile sFileName
lngH = oImage.Height
lngW = oimage.Width
```

The error occurs when trying to `CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")`

The **wiaaut.dll** file resides in the **domino\data** directory -- as well as the **notes\data** directory.  I am not sure if or how any permissions may need to be set.

The LotusScript agent is signed with an ID listed in a Group in the Domino Directory that is listed in the Server doc to

> Sign or run unrestricted methods and operations

And the Security for the agent is set to

> 3. Allow restricted operations with full administrator rights.

This signing ID is working well with other agents performing restricted operations.

I think the error is specific to the WIA object.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What OS version is the server running on? Is it running as a service? I don't know much about WIA, but from what little I've read about it I have a feeling that it includes capabilities that services can't get at due to security restrictions in more recent versions of Windows.

Comment: The OS is Windows Server 2012 R2.  Domino 9.01 server (64-bit) is running as a service.  Notes Client is Domino Developer (32-bit).

Comment: Are you using the 64bit version of the dll?  Your dll bitness needs to match your domino bitness.

Comment: Yes, the server is running 64 bit windows and the Notes client is running in 32 bit mode.  I am checking into the proper drivers and registration for 64 bit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it runs in the client, it must be using a 32 bit DLL (as per the comment by @FruitySoup). That same DLL can't work from 64 bit code.

Also, createObject relies on registry entries. AFAIK, dropping it in the data directories shouldn't actually make any difference. On my 64 bit machine, registry entries are found in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WIA.ImageFile, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ SOFTWARE\Classes\WIA.ImageFile, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID{long id here}\InProcServer32. Those keys pretty clearly indicate that it is 32 bit software.

Comment: Thanks.  What DLL should I then be using/registering for WIA?  Is the registry key above using the 32 bit DLL?  How would I register the 32 bit wiaaut.dll via wow6432Node?

Comment: I don't know. It's a Microsoft component. That's all I know about WIA. But my point is that I believe very strongly that you cannot, under any circumstances, call the 32 bit DLL from the 64 bit Domino server code. As far as I know, the magic that is done by SysWow6432 works only if the entire process is 32 bit. I.e., it allows 32 bit EXEs to find and load 32 bit DLLs and run as a 32 bit process on a 64 bit OS. It cannot make a 64 bit EXE running in a 64 bit process load a 32 bit DLL. You would need a 64 bit version of WIA, assuming it exists.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to use Java for the image resizing, unless I can find the 64 bit version of WIA.

Answer (score 2):

For using the functions in a DLL file using CreateObject() method, You not only need to copy paste the DLL file to a folder in server machine but also you need to REGISTER the DLL file in the machine.

Try registering the DLL file first using "Regsvr32" command. Registering DLL command syntax may vary depending on the machine type if it is 32 or 64 bit machine.

http://www.wikihow.com/Register-a-DLL

See if this helps.

The Readme.txt file that comes along with the dll file from the below site says you need to copy the dll file to System32 folder and register it before using the dll.

http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/imageapi/mswaidll.htm

============

## ReadMe.txt

### Getting Started

```
To install the Windows Image Acquisition Library v2.0, 
copy the contents of this compressed file to a directory on your hard drive.

Copy the wiaaut.chm and wiaaut.chi files to your Help directory (usually located at C:\Windows\Help)

Copy the wiaaut.dll file to your System32 directory (usually located at C:\Windows\System32)

From a Command Prompt in the System32 directory run the following command: 

    RegSvr32 WIAAut.dll
```

### Errata

When using the VideoPreview control, some webcam drivers have a bug that will cause the ExecuteCommand call in the sample below to hang while the VideoPreview is paused.

```
Dim Itm 'As Item

VideoPreview1.Pause = True
Set Itm = VideoPreview1.Device.ExecuteCommand(wiaCommandTakePicture)
```

The Windows Image Acquisition Library v2.0 is only designed to support the PNG, BMP, JPG, GIF and TIFF image formats.  It should not be relied upon to support other formats, though they may appear to be supported depending on system configuration.

Comment: Thank you.  The 32 bit WIA DLL is registered, but I either need the 64 bit DLL for wiaaut.dll or figure out how to use wow64 drivers to help.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried copying the 32bit DLL file  to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder and register the dll from this folder..  


I beleive you can register 32bit dll in 64bit machine and use it's functions.




http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439845/register-32-bit-com-dll-to-64-bit-windows-7



For 32 bit DLLS in Windows 64 bit platforms:

Copy whatever.dll to c:\windows\sysWOW64\
Open a CMD prompt AS ADMINISTRATOR (very important)
In the CMD window:

CD c:\windows\sysWOW64\
regsvr32 whatever.dll
You will then be executing the 32-bit regsvr (c:\windows\sysWOW64\regsvr.exe) on a 32 bit dll