# Remote Desktop connection feature in Delphi(RDP protocol implementation)

Tags: delphi, com, activex, remote-desktop, delphi-xe5

I want to implement Remote Desktop connection feature in my application which is written in Delphi.I imported the ActiveX control("Microsoft Terminal Services Active Client Type library(mstscax.dll), created a new package with the imported unit, successfully compiled and installed this new ActiveX control.

But when I try to set the properties of the installed MsTscAx control, ide gives `Class not registered` exception..
I tried registering the mstscax.dll by executing

```
Start> Run> regsvr32 C:\Windows\System32\mstscax.dll
```

The dll gets registered successfully but ide still raises the exception `Class not registered`
Please help..

Comment: Is there a 32/64 bit issue. Perhaps there is only a 64 bit control registered.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my development machine is 64  bit and I tried with registering both 32 and 64 bit version of the dll.But the exception still persists..

Comment: Perhaps you didn't actually register a 32 bit control. Perhaps there is no 32 bit control. Perhaps it is 64 bit only. It's quite tricky to register a 32 bit control. You need to know the magic incantations. Perhaps you don't. We can't tell because so much detail is missing.

Comment: The IDE is 32 bit, do you have a dll under C:\Windows\SysWOW64 ?

Comment: @whosrdaddy my system is 64 bit and mstscax.dll is present in both System32 and SysWOW64 folders.I first registered the dll from System32 but the exception got raised so I tried with the dll from SysWOW64 folder.But IDE still raises the exception..

Comment: Did you use the 32 bit version of RegSvr? look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3440419/800214)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Register 32 bit COM DLL to 64 bit Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439845/register-32-bit-com-dll-to-64-bit-windows-7)

Comment: Leave the IDE aside. Can you instantiate the control with runtime code and set the properties in code. This is a non visual component. No need to set properties in the designer. A much over rated feature.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I tried registering the 32 bit dll from regsvr32 from windows\SysWOW64 still din't help..

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can instantiate the control with run time code and set the properties..
This is my code
 MsTscAx1.Server := '192.168.1.54';
 MsTscAx1.Connect;

 the code compiles successfully but the exception comes for the first statement when i try to debug or run..

Comment: What exception? Class not registered? Which class is not registered?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am getting exception class EOleSysError with message 'Class not registered'.I think this is similar exception when an ocx is not registered

Comment: Which class is not registered? Do some debugging.