# What does IIS 7.5 need to run my vb6 32bit DLL?

Tags: dll, asp-classic, vb6, iis-7.5

I have a DLL (written in VB6) that is registered and works in a VB6 exe just fine. But on the same machine when I attempt to create the server object in CLASSIC ASP, IIS7.5 just hangs on that.

```
...
dim bob as object

Set bob = Server.CreateObject("project.classname")
...
```

I know very little about managing IIS. I have tried to register this DLL inside the Modules section but that did no good. so I removed it. At one point I even killed ASP pages from loading at all with my experimentation and that required I actually edit the applicationHost.config file to remove all mention of my DLL.

I feel confident this is an IIS issue with my DLL but none of my googling has gotten me hits I either could understand or that worked.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks
Harry

Comment: Couple of things, 1. Does the Application Pool the Web Application is using have `Enable 32 bit Applications` set to `True`? 2. Does the DLL have a compatible COM interface *(`iDispatch` to support late binding, early binding is not supported)*?

Comment: Thanks Lanky. When I get home I'll look at that 32 bit apps is set to. I would think since the same Object is referenced in my ASP page from VS2017 when I test it  - it runs fine.  Some setting from VS's built in IIS is correct while my machines actual IIS isnt is my lead theory.  But I have no clue how to peek in at what VS2017 has happening there.....

Comment: @Lankymart a VB6 DLL would have the COM interfaces setup pretty much automatically, wouldn't it?

Comment: @HarryA how did you determine that is the line it hangs on?

Comment: @DaveInCaz to be honest i’m not 100% sure but if it doesn't implement the `iDispatch` interface it won’t work with late binding in VBScript. Have seen similar questions asked over the years, hence the advice.

Comment: I've had to take the indirect route to figure out that was the line but I am confident it IS the line at fault. I can't catch this error in the VS2017 debugger because it doesnt occur with the VS iis localhost  that VS uses. It behaves correctly there. But I did think to comment out the createobject line and run the page on IIS server. And then the page loads. When I click on submit it bombs. but it bombs with exactly the error I was expecting - the object doesnt exist so I cant call its method/function.  Uncomment the createobject line and run it again - it hangs....

Comment: also note that late binding in my vb6 exe test file gets this dll loaded without incident.

Answer (score 1):

Try registering the VB (COM) DLL with regsvr32 on the machine. Assuming it's a 64-bit OS, make sure to use `regsvr32.exe` from the `%Windows%\SysWOW64\` folder, not then one in `%Windows%\System32`. It actually *is* different.

See [this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439845/register-32-bit-com-dll-to-64-bit-windows-7).

Comment: WOW, never thought of that....I'll have to get back to that shelved project and try it out. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the App Pool to Classic?  It is a backwards-compatibility mode.  You can see more in the docos:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/

Comment: I did that early on. It helped with my early progress, but this road block came later.